# Should we edit obviously wrong questions?

Tags: discussion, editing, question-quality

[Why was Benjamin Sisko appointed captain of DS9 given that he has a foul temper with poor emotional control?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/147505/why-was-benjamin-sisko-appointed-captain-of-ds9-given-that-he-has-a-foul-temper)

> Benjamin Sisko is prone to emotional outbursts. He has a foul temper and has poor emotional control compared to Picard. Why was he appointed captain of DS9 given these weaknesses?
>
> Bosses with foul tempers make poor leaders because they are unpleasant
>   to work with. Would you want to work under such a boss?

The question above appears to be incorrect. Ben Sisko was appointed **commander** of DS9 and then later was promoted to captain. Others' answers included the correction, but should the question itself be edited?

Answer (score 16):

Since the edit (if done properly) would not change the **fundamental basis of the question**, I see no harm.

The OP clarified his question in a comment

> I am questioning why he was even given a leadership role given his poor emotional control. The good leaders I have met have good emotional control.

Changing

> Why was he appointed captain of DS9 given these weaknesses?

to

> Why was he appointed to a leadership role  of DS9 given these weaknesses?

does not seem like a harmful edit to me. I almost went ahead and made it myself.

Comment: So... Yes, as long as it doesn't alter the intent behind the question? If the intent is unclear, then just comment?

Comment: If the question is unclear..then yes, comment, DV or CV as you wish.

Comment: For the record, he was the captain of the Defiant before he was made a Captain. I don't believe the same applies to space stations though.

Answer (score 10):

When you spot an obvious error, you should absolutely correct it, ideally as soon as possible in order to prevent the OP from suffering from drive-by downvotes (from users who've stopped by to downvote *the error* rather than the question itself).

In this instance, I've changed the word "***Captain***" (which is a glaring error, Sisko wasn't made Captain until much later in the show) for "***Put in command***" which doesn't change the meaning one iota but does remove the mistake.